# Wrap <a> tags around <img /> with href = img src?

Tags: jquery, class, anchor, image

Trying to wrap an  tag around an image, addClass and input src of img as href of  tag:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".new img").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').addClass('image');
    var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src);
    $(this).wrap(a);
});
});
```

My HTML:

```
<img class="new" src="pic0.png" title="Image_Title"/>
```

Can't seem to get this to work. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things. Firstly, you have your selector backwards -- it should be `img.new`.  Secondly, `attr` returns a string, not jQuery, so you can't chain it.  Do the following and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.new").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.attr('src');
        $this.addClass('image');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src);
        $this.wrap(a);
    });
});
```

Comment: If I did this with a .click(function(), I'm thinking I should add unwrap in some way?

Answer (score 6):

Your selector just needs an adjustment, this:

```
$(".new img")
```

Should be:

```
$("img.new")
```

The `new` class is *on* the `<img>` itself, the `<img>` isn't a descendant of a `class="new"` element, which is what your current selector is looking for.  Also [`.attr('src')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets a string, so you need to add the class before calling it, overall like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("img.new").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).addClass('image').attr('src');
    var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src);
    $(this).wrap(a);
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/SdsbR/), or a bit simpler/faster version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SdsbR/1/):

```
$(function() {
  $("img.new").each(function() {
    var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', this.src);
    $(this).addClass('image').wrap(a);
  });
});
```